# Restore all layered pane components in their positions and repaint them

Tags: codenameone

This question is related to this: [Keep Codename One components in invalid positions after app stop/resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589182/keep-codename-one-components-in-invalid-positions-after-app-stop-resume)

In the linked question, the solution proposed is to use a fake layout. I tried that, but it produces side effects when I try to restore the original layouts.

I tried a completely different approach, that works fine on Android. **My question is why the following code works well in Android only (it doesn't work on iPhone, that seems to ignore that code) and if there are small changes that make that code working also on iPhone.**

The code:

```
private Map<Component, Dimension> layeredPaneCmps = new HashMap<>();

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        layeredPaneRestore(); // it works on Android, but not on iOS
        return;
    }
    [...]
}

public void stop() {
    current = getCurrentForm();
    if (current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog) current).dispose();
        current = getCurrentForm();
    }
    layeredPaneSave(null);
}

/**
 * Save the position of all layered pane components in a recursive way: just
 * invoke with null as cnt.
 *
 * @param cnt
 */
private void layeredPaneSave(Container cnt) {
    if (cnt == null) {
        layeredPaneCmps.clear();
        cnt = Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getLayeredPane(this.getClass(), true);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        layeredPaneCmps.put(cnt.getComponentAt(i), new Dimension(cnt.getComponentAt(i).getX(), cnt.getComponentAt(i).getY()));
        if (cnt.getComponentAt(i) instanceof Container) {
            layeredPaneSave((Container) cnt.getComponentAt(i));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Restores all layered pane components in their position and repaints them.
 */
private void layeredPaneRestore() {
    Container layeredPane = Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getLayeredPane(this.getClass(), true);
    for (Component cmp : layeredPaneCmps.keySet()) {
        cmp.setX(layeredPaneCmps.get(cmp).getWidth());
        cmp.setY(layeredPaneCmps.get(cmp).getHeight());
        cmp.repaint();
    }
    layeredPane.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android and iOS have very different suspend/resume behaviors where iOS tries to minimize repaints and back-grounding while Android constantly suspends/resumes. I would suggest logging in the `stop()`/`start()` method to make sure they aren't invoked multiple times.

Notice that you shouldn't invoke `repaint()` it would be invoked for you. Since a repaint() might trigger a layout this could be a problem. Also the `repaint()` of the parent component loops into painting the components so `layeredPane` would be enough and doesn't require also `cmp.repaint();`.